# C++ None of my files have a type

Tags: class, object, types

So I split my files into a few pieces and now i'm getting a bunch of type errors. Such as:

`phoneNUmber.h 'istream does not name a type'`

What's this mean exactly? Here's my files they're pretty short.

**Main**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "phoneEntry.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    PhoneEntry entry;
    ifstream filezilla;
    filezilla.open("phone.txt");

    if(filezilla)
    {
        while(!filezilla.eof() && entry.readEntry(cin))
        {
            entry.writeEntry(cout);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Four Oh Four - File Not Found" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Phone Entry**

```
#include "phoneNumber.h"

class PhoneEntry
{
    private: 
        PhoneNumber phone;
        string firstName,
               lastName;
        void _writeDots(ostream& fout, int n) const;
    public:
        istream& readEntry(istream&);
        ostream& writeEntry(ostream&) const;

};

istream& PhoneEntry::readEntry(istream& Sin)                    
{
    Sin >> firstName >> lastName;
    phone.readNumber(Sin);

    return Sin;
};

ostream& PhoneEntry::writeEntry(ostream& Sout) const            
{   
    const int num = 28;
    int fill = num - ((firstName + lastName).length());

    Sout << firstName << ", " << lastName;

    _writeDots(Sout, fill);
    phone.writeNumber(Sout);

    return Sout;
};

void PhoneEntry::_writeDots(ostream& fout, int n) const
{
    if(n % 2)
    {
        fout << ".";
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        fout << " .";
    }
};
```

**PhoneNumber**

```
class PhoneNumber
{
    private: 
        int areaCode, 
            prefix, 
            suffix;
    public: 
        istream& readNumber(istream&);
        ostream& writeNumber(ostream&) const;
};

istream& PhoneNumber::readNumber(istream& Sin)                  
{
    Sin >> areaCode >> prefix >> suffix;
    return Sin;
};

ostream& PhoneNumber::writeNumber(ostream& Sout) const          
{
    Sout << " " << areaCode << "-" << prefix << "-" << suffix << endl;
    return Sout;
};
```

Comment: have you tried putting `#include <iostream>` in your PhoneNumber.h file?

Comment: but im including it from the file with main() so it should trickle down to phoneNumer right? it goes to phoneEntry to phoneNumber, so I shouldn't need it should i?

Comment: my C++-fu is weak but asking why you'd need it would be a good follow-up question.

Comment: What happens when the compiler compiles `phoneNumber.cpp`? When the compiler looks at that, it's completely ignoring your main file.

Comment: gotcha so it's not going to inherit it.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee: No, each cpp file is compiled as its own compilation unit. Include files will nest, but only inside include files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's this mean exactly?

It means that the compiler thinks `ifstream` is a variable name, with no associated type. It thinks this, because it hasn't been given the class definition for `ifstream` due to you missing the proper include files:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
```

Additionally, in PhoneEntry.cpp and PhoneNumber.cpp

everyplace you have a `istream` it should be `std::istream`

Same with `ostream` and `ifstream` etc.

In your `main.cpp` you have the following statement `using namespace std;` which imports the `std` namespace into the global namespace, thus inside that file, you don't have to prepend the namespace `std::` to all the iostream calls.

Since you split things out, each new cpp file no longer has the `std::` in it's global namespace, thus you have to do it yourself.

You could add `using namespace std;` inside your cpp files, but I usually don't.